# Proof that the zero solution of equation $y''+f(y)=0$ is sustainable

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this prolem. Let $f(0) = 0$ and $tf(t)>0$ for $t \neq 0$. Proof that the zero solution of equation $$y''+f(y)=0$$ is sustainable. I thin it is a bad way to solve it by using defenition of sustainable, because it is hard to write out an explicit decision. I tried to use the Lyapunov function. $$y'(t)=-\int^{t}_{0}f(y(s))ds = F(y)$$
Define the Lyapunov function $V(y)=F(y)y$ $$V(y)>0, y\neq 0. V(0)=0$$
it remains to check the last property
$$\frac{dV(y)}{dt}=\frac{dF(y)}{dt}y+y'(t)F(y)=-f(y)y+F^2(y)=-f(y)y+(\int^{t}_{0}f(y(s))ds)^2$$ We have to proof thatn $\frac{dV(y)}{dt}\leq0$ But there i am stucked. Do you have ideas or it is a wrong way?

Comment: By "sustainable" do you mean "stable"?

Comment: @RobertIsrael, yes)

Answer (score 0):

**Does this help?**

$$y''+f(y)=0 \implies 2y'y''=-2f(y)y' \implies \frac{dy'^2}{dt}=-2f(y) \frac{dy}{dt}$$ $$\implies \int \frac{dy'^2}{dt} dt=-2\int f(y) dy \implies \frac{dy}{dt}=\pm \sqrt{A-2\int f(y) dy}$$
$$\implies \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{A-2\int f(y) dy}}=\pm t+B$$

Comment: Not enought, how i can continue? :c